# Create a type where its attributes are in a interface/type using generics

Tags: typescript, axios, typescript-generics

I am create a type based on API response for **AxiosError**.

```
errors: {
   Property: [string]
}

Example:

export interface User {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

Expected API output

errors: {
   username: [string]
   password: [string]
}
```

I'm currently writing the type (below) however I received the following error and will need advice whether I'm implementing correctly and the solution to this.

```
export type ClassError<T> = {
 [keys in T]: Array<string>; //Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'
}

export type PayloadError<T> = {
 errors: string | ClassError<T>;
}
```

Comment: Your code should be slightly more comprehensive, as to being reproducible. Currently, it's unclear which value is compared against which type.

Comment: Note that `[string]` is *not* the same type as `string[]` or `Array<string>`.  The former is a single-element [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types); that is, a value of type `[string]` is an array of length 1.  If you mean `string[]` instead, you should probably [edit] your example.

Comment: Note that the `K` in a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) like `{[K in XXX]: YYY}` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter and *not* a key name, and thus is it conventional to give it a single uppercase character name like `K` or maybe a short UpperPascalCase string like `Key`, but not a lowerPascalCase identifier name like `keys`.

Answer (score 1):

You're just looking for [the `keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) which gives you the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of known keys of a type:

```
export type ClassError<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Array<string>;
}

type UserErrors = ClassError<User>;
/* type UserErrors = {
    username: string[];
    password: string[];
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.8.2#code/LAKFFMA8AcHsCcAuACAlgO0eeAzAhgMbjICqAztsgN6jJ3ICuF86eAtuAFzJmLwYBzANy160PGTIB3BABNuvfumGgAvqAgwEKRAE9oxAMIAbCWQCi8eAgA8AFQB8yALzVRdANoBpNOmQBrcF1YHGQ7AF1uAEErPF0bRUEHERB1MBA9A1JmS2t4MhdkEzNc23JsZNAAegAqZEzicvhS-MKaEHpGZlYOBT5BD3CUzvFJGXh5Hn7lQZTVZBqqoA)